# Grub problem after updating kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, bios, acpi, certificates

my grub isn’t working. I recently updated my kernel and i think its the start point of this errors:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate which version of Ubuntu you are using and the version of kernel you upgraded to.

Comment: Did you follow the hints in the error message?